# How to add a released .whl to requirement.txt?

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, requirements.txt

If I have a Python project that depends on another public project, and this public project can only be installed through downloading the released `.whl`, how should I add this dependency to a `requirements.txt` file?
We will assume that this public project cannot be installed by cloning and `python install -e .`

The `.whl` distribution artifact is at a `https://` URL, but it seems to me like *pip* does not support installing from wheels at `https` URLs, does it?

Comment: Is the wheel file (`.whl`) on a package index such as _PyPI_ (or similar) or not? -- As far as I know, yes *pip* can install a wheel identified by its remote *https* URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a *pip* `requirements.txt` file, it is possible to list a wheel by its URL. For example, something like the following should work with `python -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt`:

`requirements.txt`

```
https://host.example/path/to/somelibrary.whl
```

***References***:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/
- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/dependency-specifiers/

Answer (score 1):

You specify dependencies by their Python package name (`foo`), not the name of the *distirbution package* (e.g., a `wheel`) that might supply the Python package. `pip` will take care of downloading/using a `.whl` file if available.

Comment: I think it is true only if the project is published on a package index (such as _PyPI_), or at least something that works with `--find-links`. If the only thing OP has is the static URL of that one `.whl` file (whose filename might not even follow correct naming scheme), then I am not sure this suggestion is helpful.

Comment: How `pip` finds the Python package is a separate issue from how you specify that a project needs the package.

Comment: OP is asking about how to add to a `requirements.txt` file, not a project's packaging metadata. So, as far as I know, the true name of the dependency does not really matter, the dependency's true name is not necessary in a `requirements.txt` file.